# Selecting rows based on sum over multiindex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(365)
rows = 100
data = {'Month': np.random.choice(['2014-01', '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04'], size=rows),
        'Code': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=rows),
        'ColA': np.random.randint(5, 125, size=rows),
        'ColB': np.random.randint(0, 51, size=rows),}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[((~((df.Code=='A')&(df.Month=='2014-04')))&(~((df.Code=='C')&(df.Month=='2014-03'))))]
dfg = df.groupby(['Code', 'Month']).sum()
```

Above gives my dataframe. I want to select only those entries which have sum (of ColA) over 1000 when this sum is performed over level[0]

```
dfg.ColA.sum(level=[0])

dfg[dfg.ColA.sum(level=[0])>1000]
```

Above one throw an error?
Expected output is :

```
        ColA  ColB
Code Month              
B    2014-01   477   300
     2014-02   591   167
     2014-03   522   192
     2014-04   367   169
C    2014-01   412   180
     2014-02   275   205
     2014-04   901   309
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Edited to include expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way to do the same:

```
groups = [g for _,g in df.groupby('Code') if g.ColA.sum()>1000]
pd.concat(groups).groupby(['Code', 'Month']).sum()
'''
              ColA  ColB
Code Month              
B    2014-01   477   300
     2014-02   591   167
     2014-03   522   192
     2014-04   367   169
C    2014-01   412   180
     2014-02   275   205
     2014-04   901   309
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the sum values across `level=0` index

```
dfg[dfg.groupby(level=0)['ColA'].transform('sum').gt(1000)]
```

---

```
              ColA  ColB
Code Month              
B    2014-01   477   300
     2014-02   591   167
     2014-03   522   192
     2014-04   367   169
C    2014-01   412   180
     2014-02   275   205
     2014-04   901   309
```